# click events registering on image only when the pixel clicked isn't transparent?

Tags: javascript, html, image

Is it possible for click events to register on an image only when the pixel clicked isn't transparent?

If I have a right triangle image, only have the click event register on the actual triangle itself, rather than the whole box, half of which is empty.

Is this even possible without using `<canvas>`?

I'm already using jQuery in the project, if it has some way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with plain html and an image.

You might be able to get away with a (relatively unsupported still afaik) css background clip, or using an (and I can't believe I'm recommending this) image map. More code-heavy options would include checking the pixel at the point clicked, but JS doesn't always have access to image data (depends on the browser) and an ajax request for the server to do this would be overkill I think. Canvas and SVG might be decent options for you, but they introduce additional dependencies that you have to be aware of that might not be worth it.

Alternately, you can [create the triangle in HTML/CSS](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/). :)

Comment: Really?  Image maps are not plain html?

Comment: Thanks. I have to use images (and other odd shapes) in this case, but would the css triangle register clicks in the right place?

Comment: They don't do what he's asking — they are a workaround to get similar behavior. And they're deprecated, and they were hideous to begin with.

Comment: @Robert_Nachos Maybe. Maybe not. I haven't played with them for this sort of thing.

Comment: @coreyward, I don't think you know what you're talking about.  Please show me where it says here that maps are deprecated:  http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/map

Comment: Additionally, these CSS-generated triangles aren't going to help you with what you're looking to do.  Check the HTML in the link included in this answer.  The triangle is rendered within a DIV - a square.  So if you add a click handler to that DIV, the transparent areas will still be clickable.  I don't get why you'd mark this as the right answer..  but to each his own.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an [image map](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_map.asp) to go around the non-transparent part of the image and handle its clicks.  And image maps do support the [onclick event attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_map.asp#table6).